# You cannot upload a video larger than 1GB

Tags: video, youtube

I took a video with my DroidX and when I use the menu to share it with YouTube I get the message "You cannot upload a video larger than 1GB." So I tapped on the info icon on the video and it says that the file size is 222MB. So why does it think that this video is >1GB and prevent me from uploading it.

Other info:
I've uploaded plenty of videos from this phone before but they were of shorter duration. This one is 3 minutes long.
I am connected to wifi.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the metainformation about the file is incorrect, try to copy to a pc and check it (right-click -> Properties)

Comment: Yes - checked that. On PC it's the same size as being reported on Droid.